# Por quê preciso executar esse código duas vezes pra girar o objeto 3d?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Meu código está uma gambiarra, mas só consegui da forma como está abaixo.

Além disso tenho que executar duas vezes para poder o objeto girar e não sei o porquê.

Gostaria de entender o que acontece aqui.

```
var device3d = helixViewport3D.Children[0];
var matrix = device3d.Transform.Value;
matrix.Rotate(new Quaternion(new Vector3D(1, 0, 0), 1));
device3d.Transform = new MatrixTransform3D(matrix);
helixViewport3D.Children.RemoveAt(0);
helixViewport3D.Children.Add(device3d);
```

Comment: Ícaro, se eu fosse votar pra fechar a sua pergunta seria como não clara. Você não havia colocado a tag da Unity3d, mas isso já foi resolvido pra você. De todas as formas, quando você diz que o objeto "gira", o que *exatamente* você quer dizer? Procure ilustrar o seu cenário, talvez com imagens (pequenas!) de antes e depois do objeto sendo girado ou com algum esboço do eixo e ângulo do giro intencionado e realizado. Ou, melhor ainda, forneça um [mcve] para que alguém interessado em te ajudar consiga ao menos testar o seu problema.

Comment: @LuizVieira Também me senti inclinado a votar para fechar. Se eu não tivesse colocado a tag do unity3d, ela já tinha ido pro espaço. Entretanto, mesmo como está e tendo arriscado postar uma resposta, eu ainda a vejo como uma pergunta que está em cima da linha do "deve ser fechado vs ainda dá para responder". Ícaro, considere o comentário do Luiz aí em cima para melhorar a sua pergunta e deixá-la perfeitamente respondível para todos. Mesmo para escrever a minha resposta, eu tive que adivinhar e arriscar algumas coisas, o que não é um bom sinal.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Eu achei a sua resposta muito boa (e até votei nela). Só que não sei se ela ajuda *de fato* o AP com base nos comentários que vcs trocaram depois. E a culpa é do fato de que a pergunta não está suficientemente clara (apesar de não estar totalmente ruim). Ícaro, melhore a pergunta se possível, considere [aceitar a resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta) do Victor se ela te ajudou, e lembre-se que vc pode abrir novas perguntas se tiver outras dúvidas relacionadas. Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] e, principalmente, leia [ask].

Answer (score 4):

A sua pergunta não está clara, mas como eu já mexi com Unity3D, eu vi que é disso que você está falando, não apenas de C#.

Vamos explicar o código, linha a linha:

```
var device3d = helixViewport3D.Children[0];
```

Não sei exatamente o que é o `helixViewport3D`, mas pelo jeito que está sendo usado é alguma coisa que contém um ou mais objetos como filho. O primeiro desses objetos é o `device3d`, que suponho ser um `GameObject`.

```
var matrix = device3d.Transform.Value;
```

Cada objeto tem uma matriz associada. Essa matriz contém dados sobre a posição do objeto no mundo virtual, bem como o seu tamanho e a sua orientação. Os detalhes do funcionamento matemático da matriz são difíceis de se entender, pois exigem um conhecimento avançado em álgebra linear.

Entretanto, a API do Unity3D abstrai os detalhes matemáticos sangrentos de forma que você possa trabalhar com essas matrizes sem precisar entrar tão profundamente nos detalhes da matemática que está por trás disso.

```
matrix.Rotate(new Quaternion(new Vector3D(1, 0, 0), 1));
```

Esse `Quaternion` criado é um conjunto de valores que representa uma rotação em 90 graus. Novamente, o fundamento matemático por trás é complicado, mas ele é abstraído. Essa rotação é aplicada à matriz. Vez que a matriz representa a posição de algum objeto, juntamente com o seu tamanho e rotação, essa operação vai rotacionar o objeto em 90 graus.

```
device3d.Transform = new MatrixTransform3D(matrix);
```

Isso daí aplica a nova matriz ao objeto, o que resulta em sua rotação em 90 graus.

```
helixViewport3D.Children.RemoveAt(0);
helixViewport3D.Children.Add(device3d);
```

Essas duas linhas removem o elemento da primeira posição do `helixViewport3D` (que é o `device3d`) e o coloca lá de novo. Acredito que é totalmente desnecessário e que no fim das contas não acaba fazendo nada, mas não estou certo disso.

Como resultado dessas operações, o objeto será rotacionado em 90 graus. Ao aplicar isso duas vezes, a rotação será de 180 graus.

Comment: Na verdade, ele gira 1 grau, e eu coloquei esse RemoveAt e Add por quê quando eu atualizava o objeto colocando um "=" por exemplo, no view não aparecia o giro, é como se tivesse alguma função que atualiza e que o RemoveAt atualiza automaticamente :/

Comment: @ÍcaroDantas Não achei o construtor do `Quaternion` que você está usando na documentação: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms558504(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ÍcaroDantas Agora fiquei realmente encucado e confuso. O `Quaternion` que eu esperava ver não era esse. Então não sei.